# Adding objects created by a @classmethod to a Python list using a for loop

Tags: python, list, class, for-loop, object

I have the following list of values assigned to the variable `homeTasks`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I have a for loop to assign a list of objects of the class `Task` to the variable `allTasks`.

```
# create empty allTasks list
allTasks=[]

# create thisTask for every value of homeTasks and append to allTasks
for y in range(len(homeTasks)):
        thisTask = Task.get_task(homeTasks[y])
        allTasks.append(thisTask)
        print(allTasks[y].taskName)

# print task names from allTasks for testing:
for z in range(len(allTasks)):
        print(z)
        print(allTasks[z].taskName)
```

This gives me the following:

```
Do Dishes
Make Bed
Laundry
Study
Laundry
Elliptical
Elliptical
Laundry
Elliptical
Elliptical
Elliptical
test
0
test
1
test
2
test
3
test
4
test
5
test
6
test
7
test
8
test
9
test
10
test
11
test
```

For some reason, the last object assigned to allTasks is assigned to every index in the list. This is true for all attributes of `thisTask`.

For reference, this is what my Task class and get_task classmethod look like:

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, taskID, taskName, points, active, complete, approved, assignedUserID, createdByUserID, dateCreated, dateCompleted, frequency):
        self.taskID = taskID
        self.taskName = taskName
        self.points = points
        self.complete = complete
        self.approved = approved
        self.assignedUserID = assignedUserID
        self.createdByUserID = createdByUserID
        self.dateCreated = dateCreated
        self.dateCompleted = dateCompleted
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.homeID = homeID

    @classmethod

    def get_task(self, taskID):
        t = (taskID,)
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskID=%s", t)
        columns = [col[0] for col in cur.description]
        task = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
        self.taskID = taskID 
        self.taskName = task[0]['taskName']
        self.points = task[0]['points']
        self.aproved = task[0]['approved']
        self.assignedUserID = task[0]['assignedUserID']
        self.createdByUserID = task[0]['createdByUserID']
        self.dateCreated = task[0]['dateCreated']
        self.dateCompleted = task[0]['dateCompleted']
        self.frequency = task[0]['frequency']
        self.dueDate = task[0]['dueDate']
        self.homeID = task[0]['homeID']
        return self
```

I know the method is working right because `thisTask` has the right values each time the loop iterates. It seems like `.append` is not working because as soon as I get out of the loop, the values in `allTasks` are wrong.

EDIT: per @barny I have created a minimal reproducible example for this below:

```
import copy

# initialize Task object

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, taskID, taskName, points, active, complete, approved, assignedUserID, createdByUserID, dateCreated, dateCompleted, frequency):
        self.taskID = taskID
        self.taskName = taskName

# define method to return values

    @classmethod

    def get_task(self, index):
        taskIDList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
        taskNames = ['Do Dishes', 'Make Bed', 'Laundry', 'Study', 'Laundry', 'Elliptical', 'Elliptical', 'Laundry', 'Elliptical', 'Elliptical', 'Elliptical', 'test']
        self.taskID = taskIDList[index]
        self.taskName = taskNames[index]
        return self

# create empty allTasks list
allTasks=[]

homeTasks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

# create thisTask for every value of homeTasks and append to allTasks
for y in range(len(homeTasks)):
        thisTask = Task.get_task(y)
        allTasks.append(thisTask)
        print(allTasks[y].taskName)

# print task names from allTasks for testing:
for z in range(len(allTasks)):
        print(z)
        print(allTasks[z].taskName)
```

Also, based on feedback I now understand that `thisTask` is a reference to an object, not a fresh copy of the result of `get_task`. To that end I have tried using `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` on both `Task.get_task(homeTasks[y])` and `thisTask` to no avail. It seems like even the copy is a reference. Is there another way to go about this?

EDIT 2: Here are the ways I've tried to use copy and deepcopy:

```
for y in range(len(homeTasks)):
        print(y)
        thisTask = copy.copy(Task.get_task(y))
        allTasks.append(thisTask)
        print(allTasks[y].taskName)
```

```
for y in range(len(homeTasks)):
        print(y)
        thisTask = copy.deepcopy(Task.get_task(y))
        allTasks.append(thisTask)
        print(allTasks[y].taskName)
```

```
for y in range(len(homeTasks)):
        print(y)
        thisTask = Task.get_task(y)
        allTasks.append(copy.copy(thisTask))
        print(allTasks[y].taskName)
```

```
for y in range(len(homeTasks)):
        print(y)
        thisTask = Task.get_task(y)
        allTasks.append(copy.deepcopy(thisTask))
        print(allTasks[y].taskName)
```

In each case followed by my test:

```
for z in range(len(allTasks)):
        print(z)
        print(allTasks[z].taskName)
```

All 4 of these produced the exact same result:

```
0
Do Dishes
1
Make Bed
2
Laundry
3
Study
4
Laundry
5
Elliptical
6
Elliptical
7
Laundry
8
Elliptical
9
Elliptical
10
Elliptical
11
test
0
test
1
test
2
test
3
test
4
test
5
test
6
test
7
test
8
test
9
test
10
test
11
test
```

Comment: Please edit all relevant code including imports and data into your question as a [mre] - so anyone can make one copy from your question and paste into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same results as you put in your question.

Comment: OK, it should be reproducible now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: *How* have you tried to make/use copies of a `Task`?

Comment: I just edited my main post and pasted in the 4 ways I've tried to do it and the output I get. Sorry, should have done that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTask` does not create a new `Task` each time it is called; it always returns the *same* `Task` after modifying it with the values from the current element of `allTasks`.  So you have added *the same `Task`* repeatedly to your list, which ends up with the values from the last call to `getTask`.

One way to fix this would be to make a new `Task` from the current contents of `thisTask` each time you `append`; fox example:

```
Task(thisTask.taskID, thisTask.taskName, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

or better yet, you could modify `getTask` to do this:

```
return Task( taskIDList[index], taskNames[index], 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 )
```

Comment: Then why does `allTasks[y]` change with every loop? If it always added the same `Task` wouldn't it always be the values from the first time it was called, `allTasks[0]`?

Comment: Because t’s the final assignment in the first loop that sets the (single) value shown in each iteration of the second loop.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Is there a way to fix this? I have tried `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` to make a copy of the object and append it to `allTasks`, and it did not work, same results.